# Accessing JSON layer as a Leaflet layer outside the AJAX call

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, json

I have a had a JSON file as a layer in my Leaflet project. Now I'm trying to add it in the layer control. But somehow I can not add it. What's the problem?

Here is my code:

```
 var states =
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=dc_register:plz-1stellig&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=epsg:4326";

    const geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
};
  
    $.getJSON(states).then((res) => {
       myLayer = L.geoJson(res, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
           
                layer.bindPopup('<h3>'+"The avarage PUE for this state is: "+feature.properties.pue+'</h3>')
            
        },
        style: style,
    }).addTo(map);
    
    //map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
});

   var basemaps = {
    'Open Street Map': osm,
    'Satellite': sat,
    'Greyscale': ab}

   var overlay = {
    'PUE':states,
   }

  L.control.layers(basemaps,overlay).addTo(map);
```

Comment: It looks like you are not assigning your `$.getJSON` call to a variable. Therefore, `states` inside your `overlay` object is the original GeoServer query string in line 1.

Comment: @TomazicM sorry I thought I did it. I accepted it now as solution. It worked perfectly for me

Comment: @Matt I tried to assign a variable to the call with  var myLayer =  $.getJSON(states).then((res) => {
                myLayer = new L.geoJson(res, { ..... but it did not work...

Comment: Cross-post of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74299331/how-can-i-access-my-json-layer-as-a-leaflet-layer-outside-the-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment by @Matt :

The problem is that you use asynchronous calls and promises, therefore you cannot simply assign the myLayer to a global variable and use that in the L.control.layers call, because the promise may not have resolved yet.

I think you should create the L.control.layers before the getJSON call, and then inside the callback add the layer to the layercontrol.

```
// layerControl without overlays first
var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, {}).addTo(map);

states = "(...)"

$.getJSON(states).then((res) => {
    myLayer = L.geoJson(res, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
           
        layer.bindPopup('<h3>'+"The avarage PUE for this state is: "+feature.properties.pue+'</h3>')
            
    },
    }).addTo(map);
    
    // after we created the layer from the network call we can add it to the control. Second argument is the name to be displayed in the control.
    layerControl.addOverlay(myLayer, 'PUE');
    
    }); // end getJSON
```

See jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/x6q9guhv/1/

Comment: but wouldn't it be better to assign it to a variable. Because I also want to create a function for letting layers appear at a certain zooming level ect. If all just stays in the call then maybe I can not use the layer properly.

Comment: You have to think asynchronically. All code that needs to have a working, populated layer object needs to be run in the same temporal scope. So do all your layer-dependent stuff after the `layerControl.addOverlay` call. For longer code parts you can and should create functions in the global scope , and call those functions from the asynchronous block.

Comment: Thanks, I created a zooming function out of the call and used it within the json call.